# How change language from keyboard in raspbian

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, linux

How change language layout from keyboard like alt+shift
i can only do the following

$ setxkbmap us

$ setxkbmap sy

or

change language layout manually

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you mean but have you tried running sudo raspi-config?

Comment: i want change from language A to language B from keyboard. raspi-config keyboard settings doesn't serve that purpose am i right?

Comment: To rephrase: do you want have two keyboard layouts installed I your system and switch between them using a keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're on the command line use `sudo raspi-config`. 
Specifically for CLI: Go to "Localization options" and "Change Locale".

If you are on the desktop raspi-config is also available as an application. This is the default Raspberry Pi way  to change the keyboard lay-out.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not from the UK you might want to do some of the following:

Keyboard - look for the uk and change it to your type (us will do us, aus, can, nz etc). Then save and exit.

```
sudo nano /etc/default/keyboard
```

Locale - uncheck the uk and check the one you need and then set it as default. Mine is en_AU UTF-8

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Timezone

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

Reboot to get the full effect.