# Raspberry Pi Login Screen Change

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, raspbian-jessie

I am pretty new to raspberry pi. I was trying to change the login screen of raspbian in my native language. Can anyone please suggest how can I do that?

I already installed unicode library, installed the fonts. Now my target is to change the login screen strings like "shutdown" or "login" in my own language.

Comment: Changing the localization settings via raspi-config should change all text to your native language, to include the strings on the login page (this answer explains how to do that: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/75938/33260). Does that work for you, or do you ONLY want it changed on the login screen?

Comment: Some other guy changed some inside strings (desktop icon names, help texts, error messages etc) in my native language. When I change the localization settings the language works pretty good.
I only want to change the login screen. Not the whole theme. Just the labels of the buttons...

Comment: I actually solved the problem...thanks for your help anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it was pretty easy. I changed the default greeter from

> /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf

In that file I found “greeter session” and choose
between “lightdm-gtk-greeter” and “pi-greeter”, as the default greeter session. (You can choose your own greeter session).

Then I created a .po file and translated the strings I needed(using the "msgid" and "msgstr"). Then converted it to a .mo file and added the file in

> /usr/share/locale/(your own language folder; in my case it was bn as in Bengali)/LC_MESSAGES/

The file name should be the same as the default greeter. For example if your default greeter is "pi-greeter" the file name should be "pi-greeter.po" the converted file name should be "pi-greeter.mo"